# Why is this Bash command output different from what is expected when I run the command in Debian?

Tags: bash, read

The bash version in my system’s running version of Debian is:

```
bash --version|awk 'NR==1'
GNU bash, version 5.1.4(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

In [Eyal Levin's answer on this other Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39622629/117259) it recommends this:

```
Example:

$ echo "title\nvalue1\nvalue2\nvalue3" | (read line; echo "$line"; grep value2)

Output:

title
value2
```

In my Bash console I run this:

```
debian@debian:~$ echo "title\nvalue1\nvalue2\nvalue3" | (read line; echo "$line"; grep value2)
titlenvalue1nvalue2nvalue3
debian@debian:~$
```

Why the command output different result in my OS?

```
echo "title\nvalue1\nvalue2\nvalue3" | (read line; echo "$line"; grep value2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, `echo` behaves differently on different platforms.

So, as [this Stack Overflow answer explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8467449/117259), replace `echo` with `printf` for consistent output across different platforms.

Knowing that, change your command to use `printf` like this:

```
printf "title\nvalue1\nvalue2\nvalue3" | (read line; echo "$line"; grep value2)
```

Or you could just add the `-e` parameter to `echo` to “enable interpretation of backslash escapes” as the [`echo` man page explains](https://linux.die.net/man/1/echo).

```
echo -e "title\nvalue1\nvalue2\nvalue3" | (read line; echo "$line"; grep value2)
```

Tested this and it works on Bash on Ubuntu 20.04:

```
GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

And it also works as well on the weirdo version of Bash that macOS Monterey (12.6) Apple has cooked up:

```
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin21)
```

Comment: Don't use `echo -e`; some versions will print "-e" as part of the output. It is simply not possible to count on the output from `echo` if you pass it any options or there are backslashes in the string (see [this Unix & Linux answer for more info](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo/65819#65819)). If you want reliable results, use `printf` instead.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thus why I mentioned `printf` first.